# Why is this label showing its text string out of order?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a label, let's call it `lblText`.

Here's what's happening. I set the text:

```
lblText.text = "Some label stuff here."
```

And then it displays as `.Some label stuff here`. I tried adding a space (`Some label stuff here.`), a non-breaking space, and even an underscore(`Some label stuff here._`), but instead it just displayed `.Some label stuff here` or `_.Some label stuff here`. This is all showing on the same line.

I tested this with an event, which executes `MessageBox.Show(lblText.Text.Substring(0,1))`. This is showing that string starts with `S`. I'm at a total loss why this is happening, and it makes even less sense to me that adding an underscore *after* the period places it *before* at the start. Anyone have any hints?

I'm using VS 2005 (it's legacy code).

Comment: Something else is going on here that you aren't showing.  Does the label contain *anything* other than just the type of a car?

Comment: Hint: Try to create a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. remove *everything* until only the label and the message box is left. Is the problem still there?

Comment: Narrowed down the problem quite a bit. It's actually not appending a period; it's showing the text string out of order. I generalized the problem a bit too much without showing actual code. :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the 'RightToLeft' property turned on in your label.  Turn it off and the full stop will be in the right place.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx